# Solving this 3rd order ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following ODE’s, given that y1 = x is a solution. $$y′′′+(x^2 + 1)y′′ − 2x^2y′ + 2xy = 0$$

My attempt:
I put $y=u(x)x$ and substituted in the equation. I later put $v=u'$, since the $u$ term gets cancelled and I can convert it to a second-order ODE. I got the following ODE:

$$xv''+v'(x^3+x+3)+v(-2x^3+2x^2+2)=0$$

I can't seem to be able to solve this equation. Is my approach wrong? Is my simplification wrong? Is there some way to solve the second-order ODE?

Comment: @SrinathPrasad It is even written in the text.

Comment: Yes, my bad, that is why I deleted the comment.

Comment: Your calculation is correct but this second order DE is not easy to solve.